# IOS Core Data Cardinality issue

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm writing a simple application using TableViews and Core Data that shows a list of students in the first level and when clicked on a cell, it shows the names of the courses that student takes. I set student->courses as toMany, courses->student as toOne. This is how i pass the Student entity to course view controller for using its managedObjectContext:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Student *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CoursesTableViewController *courseViewController = [[CoursesTableViewController alloc] initWithStudentInfo:info];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:courseViewController animated:YES];
}
```

This is how i create courses inside the courses view controller(I want only three courses as named below, numberofrow is supposed to assure that):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][0];
    int numberofrow = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    NSLog(@"%d",numberofrow);
    NSLog(@"%d",[self.fetchedResultsController sections].count);
    if(numberofrow <=2){
        NSLog(@"creating courses");
        [self insertNewObject:@"comp319"];
        [self insertNewObject:@"comp314"];
        [self insertNewObject:@"comp316"];
    }
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(NSString *) str{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
    NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];


    [newManagedObject setValue:str forKey:@"course_name"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

How i create the fetchedResultsController inside courses View Controller:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Courses" inManagedObjectContext:self.studentInfo.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"course_name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.studentInfo.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Finally the problem is that when I create the first student and click on it, NSLog in viewDidLoad of courses view controller above prints "creating courses", however when i create the second student it does not and also numberofrow prints 3 where it should have printed 0 since it is a new student instance.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the NSPredicate when you create fetchedResultsController in `CoursesTableViewController`?

Comment: I copied the whole thing above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Courses" inManagedObjectContext:self.studentInfo.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

With

```
// my comment : entity here has to be your student name, why 'course'
// and also replace your search key from 'yourCourseNameKey' with 'yourStudentNameKey'
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Your Student Name" inManagedObjectContext:self.studentInfo.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

You need to **get number of Students** but you query **number of Courses**

Comment: Compiler asks for sortDescriptors.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: you still use sortDescriptor, but you should replace key 'course_name" with "yourStudentNameKey"

Answer (score 0):

You do not set a predicate on the fetch provided to the fetched request controller so you aren't searching for courses for the selected student and creating then if they aren't there. Not that that is ideal anyway (and wouldn't work because you aren't setting a relationship between the student and all of the courses).

So, most likely you should have a set of courses and a set of students. The relationship should be many:many as a course really has multiple students and each student takes multiple courses (or could anyway).

Now, your students and courses would be created 'up-front' and then your view controllers simply deal with fetching, displaying and connecting (establishing the relationships) the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I set it to many:many. However still after creating the first student, next students don't print NSLog(@"creating courses") which makes me think that they aren't creating a new Student-Course relation but overwriting the first student.

Comment: Did you just change the relationship? Because my answer says you should change your approach and not be creating multiple copies of the courses...

Comment: I'm really not sure how to relate levels of table view with Core Data. Configuring .xcdatamodeld was not sufficient to give results in the form of "student takes these courses and the course is taken by these students". None of the tutorials I could find explained this scenario.

Comment: You understand the concept of having multiple students and multiple courses and saying that some subset of students are taking one course and some other (possibly overlapping) subset of students are taking another course?

Comment: No, all the students are taking the same three courses and on a level down when they click on the course names they're supposed to see their grades in that course. However currently, since the course number is fixed and pre-defined, they appear alright but when the user edits the grade of a student it reflects to his other course grades as well as other students' grades. Sorry, I tried to simplify the question at first but it got muddled up.

Comment: Ok, so you don't really want course objects, you want grade objects, and each grade object has a course name and a score. The app shouldn't be creating any student and grade objects directly, it should be provided with them from somewhere else (like a web service). Then each student should have one grade object for each course they are taking (have taken).